# How do you grant Sonar access to Jira through Crowd?

Tags: jenkins, jira, crowd

My Jenkins build calls a Sonar task that pulls from Jira the results of a saved filter. The problem I have is that Sonar's request is always denied. I have a fairly complex cluster of machines (Jira 4.4.3, Sonar 3.2.1, Jenkins 1.473, etc) all authenticating through Crowd 2.2.2.

```
2012.10.17 12:00:03 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.SecurityServerClientImpl  Existing application token is null, authenticating ...
2012.10.17 12:00:03 ERROR o.c.x.t.h.HttpChannel  Server returned error code = 403 for URI : http://10.74.47.12:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer. Check server logs for details
2012.10.17 12:00:03 ERROR rails  Error from external authenticator: org.codehaus.xfire.XFireRuntimeException: Could not invoke service.. Nested exception is org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault: Server returned error code = 403 for URI : http://10.74.47.12:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer. Check server logs for details
```

I have verified that the account Sonar is using to contact Jira is valid and has permission to access Jira.  I have the Sonar Crowd Plugin installed and configured according to the [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Crowd+Plugin), but something isn't right. When I log into Sonar I see the following errors in the sonar.log (but my login succeeds):

```
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Loading property: 'application.name' : 'sonar'
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Failed to find value for property: application.login.url
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Loading property: 'crowd.server.url' : 'http://10.74.47.120:8095/crowd/services/'
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Failed to find value for property: session.isauthenticated
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Failed to find value for property: session.tokenkey
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Failed to find value for property: session.lastvalidation
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl  Loading property: 'session.validationinterval' : '5'
2012.10.17 15:49:53 INFO  c.a.c.i.s.s.c.SecurityServerClientImpl  Existing application token is null, authenticating ...
2012.10.17 15:49:54 ERROR o.c.x.t.h.HttpChannel  Server returned error code = 403 for URI : http://10.74.47.12:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer. Check server logs for details
2012.10.17 15:49:54 ERROR rails  Error from external authenticator: org.codehaus.xfire.XFireRuntimeException: Could not invoke service.. Nested exception is org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault: Server returned error code = 403 for URI : http://10.74.47.12:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer. Check server logs for details
```

- Key points:

  - The server logs on the Crowd server tell me nothing. There's no record of the Sonar authentication request even reaching Crowd.
  - I have defined application.login.url in both sonar-3.2.1/conf/sonar.properties AND
    Sonar-Tomcat/conf/crowd.properties, but sonar.log isn't picking it
    up.
  - Sonar IS picking up some of the information from sonar-3.2.1/conf/sonar.properties. I changed the crowd.url to see if
    sonar would register the change and it did.
  - session.validationinterval is defined as 0 in Sonar-Tomcat/conf/crowd.properties but the sonar.log shows
    session.validationinterval as 5. I can't work out where it's getting
    that value from.
  - `http://10.74.47.12:8095/crowd/services/SecurityServer` is a valid URL and there is a SOAP server available there.

I also have the Jenkins Crowd Plugin and the Jenkins Jira Plugin installed and I don't see any problems there.

Has anyone else tried this and is there some extra step I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

:) I have an answer for you!!!  I was excited when I found this a week ago.  I had a similar issue.

http://wiki.idalko.com/display/SONAUT/Sonar+Authenticator+for+JIRA

This guy forked off the code and fixed it to work with Jira embedded crowd.  I am deploying it to test servers right now...  its working great for me!